# og:image Does not appear when it should

Tags: facebook

In this website
http://www.fundacaomiguelpereira.com.br the og:image doesn't show.

Not sure what I'm doing wrong, I setup a default image for the website and already tried changing it's size to see if it shows up and changed it several times, but nothing showed up.

```
 <meta property="og:title" content="Contatos e Ouvidoria" />
    <meta property="og:description" content="Meio de contatar o Hospital" />
    <meta property="og:type" content="website" />
    <meta property="og:url" content="http://www.fundacaomiguelpereira.com.br/?page=contatos" />
    <meta property="og:image" content="http://www.fundacaomiguelpereira.com.br/assets/img/fmp/logo-hsae.jpg" />
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Did you scrape it on facebook debug?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I refreshed the OG data in the debugger, now it shows up correct: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object/

OG Data gets cached, make sure you refresh it whenever you change them.